# Perl: How to correctly initialize a hash or array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Throughout several online tutorials, I've noticed variations in how a hash or an array is initialized:

```
my %new_hash_1 = ();
# or
my %new_hash_2;

my @new_array_1 = ();
# or
my @new_array;
```

With my basic exercises of pushing elements into an array or adding key,value pairs to a hash, it doesn't appear to matter which way I initialize the variable.

With further googling, I learned that:

```
%new_hash_1 = ();
```

is sometimes used to empty out an existing hash.

So I guess my questions are:

- Which method should one use to initialize a hash/array?
- Is there a specific purpose unique to each method? Or is this an example of TIMTOWTDI?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way hashes and arrays are constructed, there is no difference if you assign an empty list to them upon declaring them. They will still contain zero elements, and any element you try and read from them will be undefined.

The only purpose of assigning an empty list to a hash/array is to remove any values it already has, and upon initialization, they contain no values.

It is important to note that arrays and hashes can only contain scalar values, and only scalar values can contain data.

Comment: If you're using mod_perl, there might be a pretty substantial difference between `our %hash;` and `our %hash = ();`. The former might retain data from previous iterations of the application, depending on scope, etc. I usually make sure to include the empty parenthesis when initializing hashes or arrays just to avoid the possibility of this becoming a problem.

Comment: The `our` keyword is rather different from `my`, yes. It does not necessarily create a *new* variable, and it has all the drawbacks of "global" variables, such as the one you mentioned.

Comment: You should always initialize all variables when you declare them. That way, you never get surprised.

Comment: @AKHolland, That's one of the reasons why should be using `local our %hash;` when you're trying to emulate lexical vars using package vars. Assigning an empty list is just as useless there.

Answer (score 3):

`my %hash` creates a new empty hash.

`my @array` creates a new empty array.

Assigning an empty list to a newly created hash or array is useless noise since the they are already empty.

Answer (score -5):

Both works but but in terms of maintenance it's best to keep them separated and to initialize Lists with parenthesis () and hashes with curly braces {}, so far my coding convention has been:
    my %new_hash_1 = {};
    my %new_list_1 = ();

This has the advantage of making it easy for whoever update your codes later on to do

```
my %new_hash_1 = { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 };
```

and will help `use strict;` and `use warnings` have better understanding of what your trying to do whenever you're using a list as a hash.

I also advises you to use PerlCritic http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic-1.118/lib/Perl/Critic.pm to get more user friendly messages.

Cheers,
Jere.

ps: see hashes of hashes in Oreilly Programming Perl (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/prog/ch09_04.htm)

Comment: This is incorrect. Using curly braces will create a hash *reference*, and if you use that in a hash assignment, you will get the error `Odd number of elements in hash assignment`. This: `{}` is a scalar value, not a list.